# How to overlay a navbar over a video background

Tags: html, css

so I have a video in the background, I'm trying to put a navigation bar over that video. So, I made them both work separately however when I put them together the video overlays the navigation bar instead. Now I have no idea what is going on wrong with this. I've added tried rearranging the code, as well as looking for guides online yet have not been able to find any specifics.

So here's my html code:

```css
    *{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
    }
    .container{
 width: 90%;
 margin: 0 auto
    }
    .navbar {
 width:100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 40px;
 line-height: 40px;
 background: #fff;
 border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    }
    .logo{
 width: 80px;
 float:left;
    }

    /* this is for ul tag */
    .menu{
 float:right;
    }
    .menu li{
 float:left;
 width:120px;
 height: 40px;
 line-height: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 list-style: none;
    }
    .menu li a{
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: calibri;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 display:block;
    }
    .menu li:hover{
 background: #dc3545
    }
    .menu li a:hover{
 color: #fff
    }
    #myVideo {
 position: fixed;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 min-width: 100%; 
 min-height: 100%;
 filter: brightness(25%);
    }
```

```html
    <head>
 <title>Guide to Sheffield Student Nightlife - Home Page</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\paulk\Desktop\Web Dev\style.css">
</head>

 <body>
 
 <div class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="logo_div">
    <a href="https://www.google.com/"><img src="C:\Users\paulk\Desktop\Web Dev\TheGuide.png" alt="" class="logo"></a>
   </div>
   <div class="navbar_links">
    <ul class="menu">
     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
   <video playsinline autoplay muted loop poster="TheGuide.jpg" id="myVideo">
    <source src="C:\Users\paulk\Desktop\Web Dev\Fire.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
 </body>
```

Comment: try `z-index:-1` to the video

Comment: Yep works like a charm, hahaha, can't believe it was that simple

Comment: have a read about [z-index's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) (only works on positioned elements)

Comment: @Pavvel happy to help you:) nice day:)

Answer (score 1):

Since your video is position: fixed you can use negative z-index

```
#myVideo {z-index: -1;}
```

Full example:

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container{
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto
}
.navbar {
  width:100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
.logo{
  width: 80px;
  float:left;
}

/* this is for ul tag */
.menu{
  float:right;
}
.menu li{
  float:left;
  width:120px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}
.menu li a{
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: calibri;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display:block;
}
.menu li:hover{
  background: #dc3545
}
.menu li a:hover{
  color: #fff
}
#myVideo {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%;
  filter: brightness(25%);
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo_div">
      <a href="https://www.google.com/"><img src="C:\Users\paulk\Desktop\Web Dev\TheGuide.png" alt="" class="logo"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar_links">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<video playsinline autoplay muted loop poster="TheGuide.jpg" id="myVideo">
  <source src="https://ak8.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/8733538/preview/stock-footage-sydney-australia-january-social-media-internet-platform-networks-social-media-allows.webm" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: It should be a comment...The OP already told me that it works because my comment